# Running sql script in sqlcmd is cutting part of my html code in file result

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I create a Script sql-server that returns two html code from two different  views that I created. The problem is that, when I'm running the .sql file (scrip) in sqlcmd, the html result in the file output is incomplete (obs. If I execute in management studio, the result in html is complete).

I have no idea how to proceed. I think in Oracle `set long` is used, but I don't know in Microsoft SQL Server.

```
--CODE IN SQLCMD
    --SQLCMD -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -i C:\checklist_sql\check_sql\checklist.sql -o C:\checklist_sql\lib\resultado.html


SET NOCOUNT ON;
    ---------ROCEDUR TO HTML----
    GO
    create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SqlTableToHtml] (
    @TABLENAME  NVARCHAR(500),
  @OUTPUT   NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,
  @TBL_STYLE NVARCHAR(1024) = '',
   @TD_STYLE NVARCHAR(1024) = '',
@HDR_STYLE NVARCHAR(1024) = '')
AS

    -- Description 
    --        Stored Procedure to take an arbitraty temporary table and return 
   --        the equivalent HTML string .


    -- @exec_str stores the dynamic SQL Query
   -- @ParmDefinition stores the parameter definition for the dynamic SQL
       DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)
       DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)


--We need to use Dynamic SQL at this point so we can expand the input table name parameter
SET @exec_str= N'
DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

--Make a copy of the original table adding an indexing columnWe need to add an index column to the table to facilitate sorting so we can maintain the
--original table order as we iterate through adding HTML tags to the table fields.
--New column called CustColHTML_ID (unlikely to be used by someone else!)
--

select CustColHTML_ID=0,* INTO #CustomTable2HTML FROM ' + @TABLENAME + ' 

--Now alter the table to add the auto-incrementing index. This will facilitate row finding
DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER=0
UPDATE #CustomTable2HTML SET @COUNTER = CustColHTML_ID=@COUNTER+1 

-- @HTMLROWS will store all the rows in HTML format
-- @ROW will store each HTML row as fields on each row are iterated through 
-- using dymamic SQL and a cursor
-- @FIELDS will store the header row for the HTML Table

DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @FIELDS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @HTMLROWS='''' DECLARE @ROW NVARCHAR(MAX) 

-- Create the first HTML row for the table (the table header). Ignore our indexing column!
SET @FIELDS=''<tr>''
SELECT @FIELDS=COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''')+''<th ' + @HDR_STYLE + '>'' + name + ''</th>''
FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#CustomTable2HTML'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID''
SET @FIELDS=@FIELDS + ''</tr>''

-- @ColumnName stores the column name as found by the table cursor
-- @maxrows is a count of the rows in the table, and @rownum is for marking the
-- ''current'' row whilst processing

DECLARE @ColumnName  NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @maxrows INT
DECLARE @rownum INT

--Find row count of our temporary table
SELECT @maxrows=count(*) FROM  #CustomTable2HTML


--Create a cursor which will look through all the column names specified in the temporary table
--but exclude the index column we added (CustColHTML_ID)
DECLARE col CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#CustomTable2HTML'')
AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID''
ORDER BY column_id ASC

--For each row, generate dymanic SQL which requests the each column name in turn by 
--iterating through a cursor
SET @rowNum=0
SET @ParmDefinition=N''@ROWOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,@rowNum_IN INT''

While @rowNum < @maxrows
BEGIN
  SET @HTMLROWS=@HTMLROWS + ''<tr>''

  SET @rowNum=@rowNum +1
  OPEN col
  FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
      --Get nth row from table
      SET @exec_str=''SELECT @ROWOUT=(select COALESCE(['' + @ColumnName + ''], '''''''') AS ['' + @ColumnName + ''] from #CustomTable2HTML where CustColHTML_ID=@rowNum_IN)''

    EXEC  sp_executesql 
      @exec_str,
      @ParmDefinition,
      @ROWOUT=@ROW OUTPUT,
            @rowNum_IN=@rownum

      SET @HTMLROWS =@HTMLROWS +  ''<td ' + @TD_STYLE + '>'' + @ROW + ''</td>''
      FETCH NEXT FROM col INTO @ColumnName
    END
  CLOSE col
  SET @HTMLROWS=@HTMLROWS + ''</tr>''
END

SET @OUTPUT=''''
IF @maxrows>0
SET @OUTPUT= ''<table ' + @TBL_STYLE + '>'' + @FIELDS + @HTMLROWS + ''</table>''

DEALLOCATE col
'

DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(max)
SET @ParamDefinition=N'@OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'

--Execute Dynamic SQL. HTML table is stored in @OUTPUT which is passed back up (as it's
--a parameter to this SP)
EXEC sp_executesql @exec_str,
@ParamDefinition,
@OUTPUT=@OUTPUT OUTPUT

RETURN 1;


---- VIEW  VERSION SQL--
GO
create view versao_sql as 
SELECT Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')) AS [NOME DA MAQUINA] ,
 Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')) AS [INSTANCIA] ,
 Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')) AS [PRODUCT VERSION],
 Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')) AS [PRODUCT LEVEL] ,
 Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) AS [EDIÇÃO] ,
 ( CASE SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Personal or Desktop'
 WHEN 2 THEN 'Standard'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'Enterprise'
 else ''
 END ) AS [ENGINE TYPE] ,
 Convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType')) AS [TIPO DE LICENÇA] ,
 convert(nvarchar(30), SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses')) AS [LICENÇAS] ,
 ( CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')
 WHEN 0 THEN 'Mista'
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Integrada'
 else ''
 END ) AS [SOMENTE SEGURANÇA INTEGRADA] ,
 convert(nvarchar(30),SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')) AS [COLLATION] ,
 ( CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')
 WHEN 0 THEN 'Nao'
 WHEN 1 THEN 'Sim'
 END ) AS [CLUSTER];


------INFO INSTANCE--
GO
create view info_instancia as
select 'VERSAO DO CHECK LIST' as DESCRICAO,'2.2.6' as VALOR
union all
select 'NOME DO SERVIDOR' as DESCRICAO, CAST(@@SERVERNAME as nvarchar) as VALOR
union all
select 'IP DO SERVIDOR' as DESCRICAO, CAST(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') as nvarchar) as VALOR
union all
select 'NOME DA INSTANCIA' as DESCRICAO, CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') as nvarchar) as VALOR
union all
select 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' as DESCRICAO, CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') as nvarchar) as VALOR
union all
select 'VERSAO SQL SERVER' as DESCRICAO, CAST(@@VERSION as nvarchar) as VALOR
union all
select 'DATA DE HOJE' as DESCRICAO, CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar) as VALOR;

-- RUNNING PROCEDURE FOR EACH VIEW
GO
--SQL VERSION
declare @html nvarchar(max)
exec SqlTableToHtml 'versao_sql', @html output, 'style="table:"border=1 width=65%"', '', 'style="scope=col"'
select @html;

GO
--INSTANCE SQL
declare @html nvarchar(max)
exec SqlTableToHtml 'info_instancia', @html output, 'style="table:"border=1 width=65%"', '', 'style="scope=col"'
select @html;

----DROPINGS----
GO
drop view versao_sql;
GO
drop view info_instancia;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE SqlTableToHtml;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here but using dynamic sql with a cursor in it is absolutely not the right way to go. I have read this question several times and I can't figure out what you are trying to do or what the issue is.

Comment: Careful, code like `' + @HDR_STYLE + '` and `' + @TABLENAME + '` is a huge injection issue and means that's a massive security flaw in your code. You should really be looking at solving that before anything. Why it's truncating, however, is because I *suspect* that your string is over 4,000 characters, but nothing is declared as an `nvarchar(MAX)`. I bet if you changed `SET @exec_str= N'DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)...` to `SET @exec_str= CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'DECLARE @exec_str  NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '...` it would work. but still, fix that injection issue!

Comment: I want to do a checklist in html, but i need to execute the script in .bat, so I´m testing using sqlcmd to run the script but the return it´s a HTML incomplete. But the script is working, because when I run in the management studio, results two complete html (two tables in html code). You need to run the scri in SQL 2017 version, because I don´t know if the script is compatible to others versions